# Spark dropping SparkListenerEvent because no remaining room in event queue

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

I am using pyspark to run my spark tasks and when I tried to execute following python script I am getting following errors.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, sum, stddev_pop, mean, length

comp_df = sqlContext.sql('SELECT * FROM default.cdr_data')
df1 = comp_df.groupBy('number', 'type', 'week').agg(sum('callduration').alias('call_sum'), count('callduration').alias('call_count'), sum('iscompethot').alias('call_count_comp'))
df2 = df1.groupBy('number', 'type').agg((stddev_pop('call_sum') / mean('call_sum')).alias('coefficiant_of_variance'), sum('call_count').alias('call_count'), sum('call_count_competitor').alias('call_count_comp'))
```

Error and Warn:

```
ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Dropping SparkListenerEvent because no remaining room in event queue. This likely means one of the SparkListeners is too slow and cannot keep up with the rate at which tasks are being started by the scheduler.
WARN scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Dropped 1 SparkListenerEvents since Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970
```

And it followed with following repeated errors,

```
ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 149 on slv1.cdh-prod.com: Slave lost
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 12.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 88088, slv1.cdh-prod.com, executor 149): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 149 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
ERROR client.TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 5181111296686128218 to slv2.cdh-prod.com/192.168.x.xx:57156: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
ERROR cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Sending RequestExecutors(83360,88076,Map(slv3.cdh-prod.com -> 88076, slv1.cdh-prod.com -> 88076, slv2.cdh-prod.com -> 88076),Set()) to AM was unsuccessful
java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 5181111296686128218 to slv2.cdh-prod.com/192.168.x.xx:57156: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:239)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:226)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:567)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetFailure(AbstractChannel.java:801)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:699)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1122)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:633)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:908)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:960)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:893)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

I tried some of the solutions,
Increased the value of `spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size`    but it did not worked. I even tried with a small dataset but still getting the error.

Comment: What's the version of Spark? Did you notice the year in "since Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970"?

Comment: probable duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152282/spark-never-finishes-jobs-and-stages-jobprogresslistener-crash Also check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18838 and vote for it !

Comment: It is known bug with spark Actual https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18881 duplicate of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18838. Need to use higher version of spark 2.3.0

Comment: apart from increasing spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventwueue.size value, try reducing the partition to avoid huge shuffles, use coalesce and reduce to smaller value,
val new_comp_df = comp_df.coalesce(10).

This will effectively reduce lot of shuffles and you will be able to avoid this warning